# Para que serve o atributo loading="lazy" em imagens e iframes?

Tags: html, html5, ux

Para auxiliar no SEO do meu site, utilizo uma extensão no Chrome chamada de Meta SEO Inspector.

Após uma atualização, ela começou a indicar que meu site precisava adicionar o atributo `loading="lazy"` nas *tags* `<img>`.

Pelo que vi da [tabela suporte](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr) da mesma, parece-me relativamente nova.

A pergunta é:

- Para que serve o atributo `loading` nas imagens?
- Como funciona a opção `lazy` no atributo `loading` especificamente?
- Esse atributo é específico da tag `<img>` ou funciona em outras tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Para que serve o atributo `loading` nas imagens?

Para destoar do comportamento padrão de carregamento das imagens em um documento HTML. O atributo `loading` é uma enumeração que pode possuir [dois valores](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#lazy-loading-attributes):

- `eager`, que faz com que a imagem seja carregada imediatamente (juntamente com o carregamento da própria página), sem considerar sua posição no documento. É o comportamento padrão.
- `lazy` (a novidade), que faz com que a imagem só seja carregada se estiver na *iminência* de entrar na *viewport* do usuário (ou seja, o que ele vê).

A vantagem imediata que se percebe é o adiamento (e eventualmente até dispensa) do carregamento de imagens que o usuário não irá visualizar imediatamente. Em ambientes (como celulares) no qual o acesso à internet é um pouco menos poderoso, deixar de carregar um recurso (como imagem) mais pesado é algo de extrema valia no quesito experiência do usuário.

## Como funciona a opção `lazy` no atributo `loading` especificamente?

O funcionamento pode variar levemente entre navegadores, mas, de modo geral, quando se define `loading="lazy"` em algum elemento que o suporte, o navegador segue [estes passos](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#start-intersection-observing-a-lazy-loading-element).

<sub>Assumindo que abaixo o termo "*imagens*" refira-se a elementos que suportam a configuração `loading="lazy"` e que esteja com o atributo `loading` definido como `lazy`, tem-se:</sub>

- As *imagens* que estão no *viewport* do usuário são imediatamente carregadas. O comportamento é análogo ao `loading="eager"`, que é o padrão.
- As imagens que estão relativamente abaixo do *viewport* do usuário não são carregadas.

  - Uma vez que o usuário, ao realizar *scroll* pela página, aproxima-se da imagem, o navegador inicia o processo de carregamento. A distância (referida como *threshhold* pode variar<sup>[[1]](https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/)</sup>) para que o carregamento inicie é variável.
  - Na maioria das vezes a imagem já terá sido carregada quando a *viewport* do usuário a atingir. Nesse sentido, na maioria das vezes, a imagem é carregada a partir da iminência de se tornar visível.

É importante frisar que, para que o navegador calcule a distância que precisa *esperar* para carregar a imagem de forma mais precisa, é **ideal** e **recomendado** que, sempre que se defina uma imagem com `loading="lazy"` também sejam especificados largura e altura (através de atributos como `width` e `height`, respectivamente). Por exemplo:

```html
<img src="image.png" loading="lazy" width="200" height="200" alt="..." />
```

## Esse atributo é específico da tag `<img />` ou funciona em outras *tags*?

Até onde pude verificar, o `loading="lazy"` é funcional em elementos de *tag* `img` e `iframe`.

## Notas finais

Esse comportamento é passível de *polyfill*. [Um exemplo.](https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill)

Como o [suporte ainda é relativamente baixo](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr), pode-se verificar se o navegador o suporta do seguinte modo:

```js
// Para <img>:
HTMLImageElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('loading'); //=> true ou false

// Para <iframe>:
HTMLIFrameElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('loading'); //=> true ou false
```

Para maior aprofundamento, sugiro a leitura [deste artigo](https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/).

Answer (score 3):

o Atributo `loading` pode ser utilizado em tags `<img>` ou em tags `<iframe>`. Ele especifica para o navegador se o carregamento das `<img>` ou `<iframe>` fora da tela do cliente, deve ser feito imediatamente ou ser adiado até que o cliente role para aonde se encontra a imagem.

****OBS: POR PADRÃO OS BROWSER CARREGAM A IMG/IFRAME IMEDIATAMENTE AO CARREGAR A PÁGINA.***

Com `loading = "eager"` carrega imediatamente isso já vem por padrão, então nem é necessário colocar isso. E o `loading = "lazy"` adia o carregamento até que o usuário role para onde está o img/iframe em questão.

Isso ajuda para deixar o carregamento da página mais rápido e leve.

Ele encurta o comprimento do [Critical Rendering Path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Critical_rendering_path).

Answer (score -3):

**Este parâmetro é usado para fins de desempenho de carregamento da pagina.**

Criado para que o site que tenha muitas imagens não demore carregar o que faz com que segundo estudos usuários mobile saiam da pagina sem consumirem o conteúdo. o `loading="lazy"` faz com que o conteúdo da pagina seja carregado e assim que totalmente carregado as imagens venham depois. **

> É um recuso para desempenho e marketing

**.

Comment: Não entendi o que tem a ver com _marketing_...

Comment: A galera usa para engajamento de conteúdo. Com tanto que o conteúdo seja lido e posteriormente as imagens sejam carregadas.